# Application not responding when CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe crashes

Tags: c#-4.0, cefsharp

I've developed an application using `cefSharp`, application is working very fine.
But when any unhandled exception occurred in application at that time `CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe` crashes and application throws message that application is not responding.

## I've used below code for checking (throws unhandled exception)

```
private void OnBrowserStatusMessage(object sender, StatusMessageEventArgs args)
{
   this.InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired(() => lblStatus.Text = args.Value);
   //Used below code to throw error for checking 
   throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid operation.");
}
```

When below code throws error application got hanged and throws message that application is not responding.

Can any one tell me how can i handle this issue.

I'm using `Chromium: 47.0.2526.80`.

Here is a sample of my debug.log from my release folder, edited to remove too many duplicates:

```
[0317/175414:WARNING:quota_manager.cc(193)] Create directory failed for path
[0317/181858:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(207)] pipe error: 109
[0317/182108:WARNING:quota_manager.cc(193)] Create directory failed for path
```

## Edit debug.log

```
[0317/175414:WARNING:quota_manager.cc(193)] Create directory failed for path
[0317/181858:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(207)] pipe error: 109
[0317/192448:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(502)] pipe error: 232
[0317/193320:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(207)] pipe error: 109
[0319/142421:WARNING:content_browser_client.cc(622)] No browser info    matching frame process id 13 and routing id 1
[0319/183359:ERROR:audio_output_device.cc(427)] IO loop going away before the audio device has been stopped
[0319/184355:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(1056)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[0319/192106:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(1056)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -100
[0319/200702:ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(13099)] [.RenderWorker-00328548]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE : glCopySubTextureCHROMIUM: source texture has no level 0
```

Comment: Your throwing an exception on a `CEF` thread. It's not like a managed thread, it's actually `unmanaged` code, so by throwing an exception you'll crash your application. You can throw your exception on the threadpool, use something like https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/47/CefSharp.Core/Internals/ReportUnhandledExceptions.h#L28 (which you can map to `c#`)

Comment: My dear friend i want to know if any unmanaged error is occurred in `cefSharp` then how can i handle this type of error, because at that time it'll affect hole application. and application throws error `Application stooped working`.Given code is just an example of unmanaged error.

Comment: Firstly your example code is rather confusing if that's what your after. Secondly I'm not aware of a way to hook the `unamanged` exception handling, remember it's `native c/c++` code, it doesn't behave like `.Net` when an error occurs. Secondly If you have a stack trace for an actual error your seeing then post a full stack trace.

Comment: My problem is that after every 2-3 hours `CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe` is crashed, but i don't know where is the issue. I've handled all `cef` events using `try catch`, but didn't get any error message.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#unmanaged-crashes-when-the-process-dies Download the release symbols as per this. You can get a stack trace. Lots of people have run `Cef` for much much longer than 2-3hrs, what are you doing differently?

Comment: I've edited my question and added debug.log result. I'm unable to understand the error. can you please help me to short this out.

Comment: Have you tried running your code on a different system? If you search for the error message you can look at the chromium source. https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/8a98b8cf09821c3b9bdc68b5d5a6fcef55e692c3/webkit/quota/quota_manager.cc#157

Comment: I've checked it on different systems, but have same issues. I've also observed  that the issue occurred only in case of pop-up window. Some times at the time of opening or at the time of closing that window. But unable in finding the issue.

Comment: Can you provide an example and a list of steps to reproduce the problem? You can use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample as a basis. Without more info there is nothing more I can add.

Comment: Actually the application is installed on users system, and i don't have any clue about the error steps. I only have debug.log records.See question edit.

There is no issue with the application when i use it from Visual Studio.

Comment: Remember this is your problem to solve, so you'll have to go the extra mile here. Doesn't seem like you've read over https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#getting-a-crash-report-from-a-customers-computer I linked to the troubleshooting `wiki` entry before.